# ps | grep shows bad output in subshell with jobs running in the background

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, ps

I am using bash. I have a file named "a2draw" that contains only 1 line:

```
sleep 99999
```

I start it using this command:

```
bash a2draw &
```

Now, I know and understand the trick with square bracket that allows you to omit grep process in ps output:

```
ps aux | grep cron
root      1079  0.0  0.0   2596   788 ?        Ss   Mar25   0:00 cron
root      1119  0.0  0.0   3684   696 ?        Ss   Mar25   0:00 /usr/sbin/incrond -f /etc/incron.conf
ja       29781  0.0  0.0   4368   820 pts/10   S+   12:49   0:00 grep cron

ps aux | grep [c]ron
root      1079  0.0  0.0   2596   788 ?        Ss   Mar25   0:00 cron
root      1119  0.0  0.0   3684   696 ?        Ss   Mar25   0:00 /usr/sbin/incrond -f /etc/incron.conf
```

But it somehow doesn't work in the subshell that has jobs running in the background:

```
jobs
[1]+  Running                 bash a2draw &

ps aux | grep [a]2draw
ja       22977  0.0  0.0   5172  1080 pts/10   S    12:21   0:00 bash a2draw
ja       30242  0.0  0.0   4364   816 pts/10   R+   12:50   0:00 grep
```

What is even more strange, dropping one letter from the process name yields correct results:

```
ps aux | grep [a]2dra
ja       22977  0.0  0.0   5172  1080 pts/10   S    12:21   0:00 bash a2draw
```

On another shell everything works as I expected:

```
ps aux | grep [a]2draw
ja       22977  0.0  0.0   5172  1080 pts/10   S    12:21   0:00 bash a2draw

ps aux | grep [a]2dra
ja       22977  0.0  0.0   5172  1080 pts/10   S    12:21   0:00 bash a2draw
```

I don't know what's going on. Is there something special about background jobs that modify how creation of pipe works?

Comment: try adding quotes around your grep pattern:    ps aux | grep "[a]2draw"

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that this also helps helps to omit grep in ps output in subshell when a2draw is running. But why?

Comment: *"What is even more strange, dropping one letter from the process name yields correct results"* That's not strange at all.  That's how grep is suppose to work (it finds patterns, which are not necessarily whole words).  Try `ps aux | grep --color=always "[a|e|i|o|u]"` and see what happens.

Comment: SuperMagic nails it, I think  : [a] will be replaced at invocation time by the shell, so grep receives "a2draw", but "[a]" will be passed to the grep, which will receive "[a]2draw" and correctly fail to see its own line (as [a]2draw matched .*a2draw.* but not .*[a]2draw.*)

Comment: the fact that sometimes you don't see grep doesn't come from dropping a letter  : it comes that you don"t always have ps showing the "grep" line AFTER grep started : sometimes it ps before grep starts, so you don"t see the grep line in the ps output. Try :   `while [ 1 ] ; do ps aux | grep a2draw | wc -l ; done` : it should sometimes show 1, sometimes 2 (depending on the output of ps, depending on the order the shell started both sides of its pipe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you used `zsh` or `(t)csh` instead of `bash`, you'd have understood your mistake:

```
$ ps -ef | grep [c]ron
zsh: no matches found: [c]ron
```

Above, you've got a globbing pattern that is meant to expand to the list of files in the current directory matching that pattern.

In most Bourne-like and rc-like shells however, if there's no matching file, the pattern is silently passed untouched to the command.

That is why it works with `[c]ron`, because there's no file called `cron` in the current directory, but not with `[a]2draw`, because there is one file matching that pattern in the current directory, it is expanded by the shell to `a2draw` and `grep` gets a `a2draw` argument instead of `[a]2draw`.

Note that `bash` can be configured to work like `zsh` in this case by doing:

```
shopt -s failglob
```

The `fish` shell also reports an error when a glob does not match. However `[...]` is not a globbing operator in `fish`.

What that means is that you need to quote globbing characters when you don't intend them to be expanded:

```
ps -ef | grep '[a]2draw'
```

You can get away without doing that in `bash` or other Bourne-like shells except `zsh`, but that makes for dormant bugs ready to kick in the day you run the command in a directory that has a matching file.

I can have nasty side effects like in unsuspected contexts. Like:

```
rm -?
```

In a directory that has files called `--`, `-x` and `-y` would remove both `-x` and `-y`.

Comment: Oh damn, that was so simple. I learn every day. I consider switching to zsh right now, it seems to have many enhancements over bash, some guy here is using it too.